# cannot pip install scikits.timeseries, no matching version

Tags: python, pip, centos7, scikits

I am running os centos7. I have installed pip. I have installed a whole bunch of python packages using pip, but I cannot seem to install scikits.timeseries.

```
[root@42b787bc6350 optimus]# pip install -vvv scikits.timeseries
Collecting scikits.timeseries
1 location(s) to search for versions of scikits.timeseries:
* https://pypi.python.org/simple/scikits-timeseries/
Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/scikits-timeseries/
Looking up "https://pypi.python.org/simple/scikits-timeseries/" in the cache
Current age based on date: 473
Freshness lifetime from max-age: 600
Freshness lifetime from request max-age: 600
The response is "fresh", returning cached response
600 > 473
Analyzing links from page https://pypi.python.org/simple/scikits-timeseries/
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement scikits.timeseries (from versions: )
Cleaning up...
No matching distribution found for scikits.timeseries
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 299, in run
requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 370, in prepare_files
ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 522, in _prepare_file
finder, self.upgrade, require_hashes)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 268, in populate_link
self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/index.py", line 491, in find_requirement
'No matching distribution found for %s' % req
DistributionNotFound: No matching distribution found for scikits.timeseries
```

Here is what happens when I specify the url:

```
[root@42b787bc6350 optimus]# pip install -vvv -i https://pypi.python.org/pypi scikits.timeseries
Collecting scikits.timeseries
1 location(s) to search for versions of scikits.timeseries:
* https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikits-timeseries/
Getting page https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikits-timeseries/
Looking up "https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikits-timeseries/" in the cache
Returning cached "301 Moved Permanently" response (ignoring date and etag information)
Looking up "https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikits.timeseries" in the cache
No cache entry available
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): pypi.python.org
"GET /pypi/scikits.timeseries HTTP/1.1" 200 15472
Updating cache with response from "https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikits.timeseries"
Analyzing links from page https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikits.timeseries
Skipping link http://www.python.org (from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikits.timeseries); not a file
Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikits.timeseries#left-hand-navigation (from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikits.timeseries); unsupported archive format: .timeseries
Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikits.timeseries#content-body (from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikits.timeseries); unsupported archive format: .timeseries
Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/pypi (from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikits.timeseries); not a file
Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=browse (from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikits.timeseries); not a file
Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=submit_form (from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikits.timeseries); not a file
Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=list_classifiers (from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikits.timeseries); not a file
Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=rss (from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikits.timeseries); not a file
Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=packages_rss (from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikits.timeseries); not a file
Skipping link http://wiki.python.org/moin/CheeseShopTutorial (from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikits.timeseries); not a file
Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/security (from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikits.timeseries); not a file
Skipping link http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=66150&atid=513504 (from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikits.timeseries); not a file
Skipping link https://github.com/pypa/pypi-legacy/issues (from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikits.timeseries); not a file
Skipping link http://www.python.org/sigs/distutils-sig/ (from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikits.timeseries); not a file
Skipping link http://wiki.python.org/moin/CheeseShopDev (from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikits.timeseries); not a file
Skipping link http://www.python.org/about (from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikits.timeseries); not a file
Skipping link http://www.python.org/news (from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikits.timeseries); not a file
Skipping link http://www.python.org/doc (from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikits.timeseries); not a file
Skipping link http://www.python.org/download (from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikits.timeseries); not a file
Skipping link http://www.python.org/community (from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikits.timeseries); not a file
Skipping link http://www.python.org/psf (from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikits.timeseries); not a file
Skipping link http://www.python.org/dev (from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikits.timeseries); not a file
Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikits.timeseries (from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikits.timeseries); unsupported archive format: .timeseries
Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikits.timeseries/0.91.3 (from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikits.timeseries); unsupported archive format: .3
Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=login_form (from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikits.timeseries); not a file
Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=register_form (from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikits.timeseries); not a file
Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=forgotten_password_form (from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikits.timeseries); not a file
Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=openid (from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikits.timeseries); not a file
Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=login&provider=Launchpad (from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikits.timeseries); not a file
Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/google_login (from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikits.timeseries); not a file
Skipping link http://pytseries.sourceforge.net (from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikits.timeseries); not a file
Skipping link https://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=239604 (from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikits.timeseries); unsupported archive format: .php
Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=browse&c=4 (from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikits.timeseries); not a file
Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=browse&c=30 (from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikits.timeseries); not a file
Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=browse&c=40 (from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikits.timeseries); not a file
Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=browse&c=60 (from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikits.timeseries); not a file
Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=browse&c=145 (from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikits.timeseries); not a file
Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=browse&c=150 (from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikits.timeseries); not a file
Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=browse&c=160 (from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikits.timeseries); not a file
Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=browse&c=174 (from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikits.timeseries); not a file
Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=browse&c=181 (from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikits.timeseries); not a file
Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=browse&c=214 (from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikits.timeseries); not a file
Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=browse&c=303 (from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikits.timeseries); not a file
Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=browse&c=385 (from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikits.timeseries); not a file
Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=browse&c=405 (from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikits.timeseries); not a file
Skipping link https://github.com/edumbill/doap/wiki (from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikits.timeseries); not a file
Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=doap&name=scikits.timeseries&version=0.91.3 (from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikits.timeseries); not a file
Skipping link http://www.python.org/about/website (from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikits.timeseries); not a file
Skipping link https://www.fastly.com/ (from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikits.timeseries); not a file
Skipping link http://developer.rackspace.com/ (from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikits.timeseries); not a file
Skipping link https://aws.amazon.com/s3/ (from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikits.timeseries); not a file
Skipping link http://www.timparkin.co.uk/ (from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikits.timeseries); not a file
Skipping link http://www.python.org/about/legal (from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikits.timeseries); not a file
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement scikits.timeseries (from versions: )
Cleaning up...
No matching distribution found for scikits.timeseries
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 299, in run
requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 370, in prepare_files
ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 522, in _prepare_file
finder, self.upgrade, require_hashes)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 268, in populate_link
self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/index.py", line 491, in find_requirement
'No matching distribution found for %s' % req
DistributionNotFound: No matching distribution found for scikits.timeseries
```

Thanks

Comment: Download it from: https://sourceforge.net/projects/pytseries/files/scikits.timeseries/0.91.3/

Comment: What is the `-vvv` switch for? Have you tried without?